# Where am I wrong - Inclusion - Exclusion

Tags: inclusion-exclusion

Thanks for looking at the question.. I have tried to solve the problem but I'm missing something..

```
Problem:

How many solutions does the equation Xl + X2 + X3 = 13
have where X l , X2 , and X3 are nonnegative integers less
than 6?
```

- I have considered that there are `C(15,13)=105` possible solutions
  without considering that `X1,2,3 <= 6` .. ( ..*.. | ..*.. | ..*..   )
- Other thing was to find how many solutions are there with x1, x2, or x3 >= 6 that would be, if I'm not wrong `C(9,7) = 36` for one of them so for all 3 would be `3*36`.. (******..|  ..*. | .*..)
- Third and last I'm considering the pairs where both have atleast value >= 6.. 
  C(3,1) = 6 .. (******.. | ****** .. | ..*..) Where are possible 3 pairs to occur .. `3 * 6`
- There can't be 3 with value >= 6
  So at the end I substracted ..

`105 - (3*36 - 3*6) = 105 - 90 = 15`

P.s solution says 6 so I'm probably wrong.. Thanks !!

Comment: Your solution first step x is less than 6 not equal to.

Comment: @Kanwaljit Singh First step is all the possible answers allowing all values

Comment: The six are $4+4+5$ or $3+5+5$  or permutations of these

Comment: @Henry Yeah it's but I can't find where I am wrong with this Inclusion-Exclusion method

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to solve: if $0 \leq x_1,x_2,x_3 < 6$, then $0< (6-x_1),(6-x_2),(6-x_3) \leq 6$. Also
$$(6-x_1)+(6-x_2)+(6-x_3) = 18-(x_1+x_2+x_3)=18-13=5.$$
Let $y_i=7-x_i$. Then we wish to know how many *positive* solutions there are to $y_1+y_2+y_3=5$. (Note: we do not have to worry about the requirement that $y_i \leq 6$, because if any of them is greater than $6$, their sum cannot be $5$.)

This is just the number of ways of placing $2$ bars in between $5$ stars so that every bar has at least one star on either side of it, e.g., $**|**|*$, which is ${4 \choose 2} = 6$ (choose the two spaces where the bars go from the four spaces between the stars).